# Lookup function dependant on a $resource

Tags: angularjs

I need a lookup function to be used throughout my application that gets additional data when provided with an id.

My attempt was to create a service:

```
angular.module("myApp")
  .factory("userResource", function($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/users");
  })
  .service("usernameLookup", function(userResource) {
    var query = userResource.query(function (data) {
      var users = data;
    };
    return function (userId) {

      // EDIT
      // How could I wait here until users is populated (and cached) the
      // first time this function is used?

      var user = { userId: 0, username: "Unknown user" }
      for (var i = 0; i < users.leng;th; i++) {
        if (users[i].id == userId)
        {
          user = users[i];
          break;
        }
      }
      return user;
    };
  })
  .controller("pageCtrl", function(usernameLookup) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.userList = [
      { userId: 0 },
      { userId: 1 }
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < userList.length; i++)
    {
      userList[i].username = usernameLookup(userList[i].userId);
    }
  });
```

(Code compressed and de-minification-proofed for brevity)

I know this is wrong since the users array might not be populated when the actual lookup happens, but I don't know how to make sure it is.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution might just be to use [`scope.$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope), updating the user list whenever it changes. If you find this distasteful (too many $watch expressions can get messy), you can create a [`userListPromise`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and only call your `usernameLookup` when the promise resolves. I can give more specific advice if you show me how the `userList` is populated, but these should be starting points.

**Edit**: I think I see what you want now.  I still think your best option is to return a promise. I know that sounds like a pain, but it's really not that bad.  Plus, when you're relying on web requests to get your data you really can't guarantee you won't end up with a 500 or 404 if the server explodes.  A robust SPA needs to assume that any web request might not work.  So here is a starting point; note that I don't handle the case when the query promise is rejected.

```
  angular.module("myApp")
  .factory("userResource", function($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/users");
  })
  .service("usernameLookup", function(userResource, $q) {
    var query = userResource.query(function (data) {
      var users = data;
    };
    return function (userId) {
      return query.$promise.then(function(users){
        var user = { userId: 0, username: "Unknown user" }
        for (var i = 0; i < users.leng;th; i++) {
          if (users[i].id == userId)
          {
            user = users[i];
            break;
          }
        }
        return user;
      });
    };
  })
  .controller("pageCtrl", function(usernameLookup) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.userList = [
      { userId: 0 },
      { userId: 1 }
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < userList.length; i++)
    {
      userList[i].username = usernameLookup(userList[i].userId);
    }
  });
```

Comment: That would be very messy for a convenience lookup :D `userList` is populated from a resource too and I could do the lookup in a chained promise, but `usernameLookup` could be used many different places so I don't want to go through that hassle every time.

Comment: @carlsb3rg I edited my answer--hopefully it's helpful.

Comment: This looks exactly like the [deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern). You can just return the `query.$promise.then(...)`.

Comment: @Tony Good point-this code is definitely not the prettiest; I was just trying to whip up a quick prototype to help the OP get started.

Comment: I noticed the anti-pattern (without knowing the name). I couldn't get the code to work straight away, but I'll get back to you when I do. A quick follow-up: is this the way to solve this problem or should I ideally get the resource to return the usernames straight away instead? I was just trying to avoid bloating the JSON by doing a lookup.

Comment: That's more a matter of opinion, but it's definitely nice to make fewer web requests and write less code to wire then together. That being said, you also want your api to be as lean and simple as possible.

Comment: @Tony Thanks for that link, btw; it was an interesting read. I updated the code to reflect it. Didn't realize I was swallowing errors by breaking the promise chain.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but at the moment it looks like your code, though sane, doesn't actually return anything :)

Comment: Well. It returns a function that takes a userId, waits for a query to finish, and finds a user returned in that query and assigns it to a local variable. Even if you return that local variable, it won't be assigned to anything accessible from outside the function unless closure and weirdness in JavaScript dictates otherwise.

Comment: @carlsb3rg woops, forgot to add the return statement back in when I edited it.  Edited answer with missing return statement. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `users` variable part of the service function:

```
.service("usernameLookup", function(userResource) {
  var users = [];
  var query = userResource.query(function (data) {
    users = data;
  };
```

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that `users` might not be populated before the lookup is called. It only avoids an error on calling length on users before JavaScript knows it's an array.

Comment: Sure, you have to call `query()` to populate the array, but it starts as an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was:

```
angular.module("myApp")
  .factory("userResource", function($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/users");
  })
  .factory("usernameLookup", function(userResource) {
    return function (user) {
      var users = userResource.query(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
          if (users[i].id == user.userId)
          {
            user.username = users[i].username;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    };
  })
  .controller("pageCtrl", function(usernameLookup) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.administratorsOrSomething = [
      { userId: 0 },
      { userId: 1 }
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < administratorsOrSomething.length; i++) {
      usernameLookup(administratorsOrSomething[i]);
    }
  });
```

I'm guessing this is more the JavaScript/AngularJS spirit of things which isn't always obvious for a c/++/# guy.

A working example with mock resources, faked latency etc can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/9Dwtqpgk7R3xuLrPAW6k)